# Can I execute ActionListener method actionPerformed from other class methods?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have

```
ActionListener actionListenerRing = new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
```

defined in my class constructor. How to call `actionPerformed` method form `main` method?

**I just wanted to know If i can call action listener directly form any other part of my class, OR I should move code form action listener to other method to be accessible to both ActioListener AND other class methods.**

Comment: Please add more code and explain your requirement better for people to suggest you right and better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you do not create a listener without attaching it to something. So if your `main` method must call such an `ActionListener` directly something might be wrong with your design. Perhaps you can comment on what you try to achieve.

You might want to read the [whole observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), but in short you add your listener to another object if you want to be informed when it performs an action. For example:

```
JButton button;//a button I obtained from somewhere and in 
// which I am interested
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){ 
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent actionEvent ){
     //do something with the fact that the button has been pressed
  }
});
```

In the above example, the button will inform the `ActionListener` I added when it's pressed, and I can react on that by placing the relevant code in the `actionPerformed` method. But I am not going to call my listener myself.

Comment: So, there's absolutely no way to call an ActionListener?

Comment: @LucasBaizer Of course there is. It has a public `actionPerformed` method which anybody can call.

Comment: @Robin I need to call such listener on Swing componend. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Make `actionListenerRing` a `static` (class) variable (assuming `main` is in the same class) instead of local to constructor then it will be accessible from the `main` and you can call the `actionPerformed` method as `actionListenerRing.actionPerformed`.

But I think calling that method manually is not a good idea.